# Convert a matrix in R into a upper/lower triangular matrix divided by secondary diagonal

Tags: r, matrix, diagonal

I know that with upper.tri() and lower.tri() I can get upper and lower triangular matrix divided by primary diagonal.

But what is the fastest way to get triangular matrix divided by the secondary diagonal?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a matrix divided by the (secondary) diagonal (which is a vector)? Please edit your question, and provide an example of a matrix and what you want as output.

Comment: Secondary diagonal == antidiagonal == the diagonal going from top right to bottom left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the code for `lower.tri`, e.g.

```
lower.anti.tri<-function(m) col(m)+row(m) > dim(m)[1]+1

m<-matrix(1:16,4)
lower.anti.tri(m)
```

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

```
m[lower.anti.tri(m)]<-NA
m
```

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   NA
[3,]    3    7   NA   NA
[4,]    4   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: Thank you, it is what I am looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply(mat, 1, rev)` to horizontally flip a matrix so flipping `lower.tri()`:

```
m <- matrix(1:16,4)
m[apply(lower.tri(m), 1, rev)] <- 0

m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    5    9   13
#[2,]    2    6   10    0
#[3,]    3    7    0    0
#[4,]    4    0    0    0
```

Comment: This is a solution, but on a big matrix it would be slower than expected